# Basic Auth curl image upload

Tags: curl

My code :

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.example.com';


$username = 'xxxxxx';


$password = 'xxxxxx';


$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  

$headers = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

Connection is ok. But I need to send an image file. I'm trying :

```
    $post = array('file' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'])));


curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

I'm posting form to this php file for image files.
Didn't work. help me please.

Comment: Can you please update with some information about the errors that you are seeing? Didn't work is not enough. Maybe add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1), remove the sensitive data and post the result. Also you don't need 'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"). Curl does by default basic authentication when CURLOPT_USERPWD is passed.

Comment: nobody can help you with that without knowing what API you're trying to use. where is the API documentation? also since base64 is a very wasteful way of uploading images, they're probably not using base64 for images, that would be a waste of bandwidth, cpu, and ram. (uploading images in the `Multipart/form-data` format, or uploading the image raw in the request body would be much more efficient)